# call compareTo method java issuess

Tags: java, sorting, oop

I am trying to build a method to sort an object property, in this example is nrPagPublicate and the method is called compareTo.
How do I have to call it? Is my interface ok?
This is where I`m stuck:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 *
 * @author alex
 */
public class Autor implements Comparable<Autor> {

   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public String nume;
    private int nrPagPublicate;
    private final int masa = 22;
    //contrusctor obiecte
    public Autor(String nume, int nrPagPublicate){
        this.nume = nume;
        this.nrPagPublicate = nrPagPublicate;     
    }
    public void vorb(){
        System.out.println(nume + " asa ma cheama pe mine!");
    }
    //setters and gettters
    public String getNume() {
        return nume;
    }

    public void setNume(String nume) {
        this.nume = nume;
    }

    public int getNrPagPublicate() {
        return nrPagPublicate;
    }
    public int compareTo(Autor CompareAutor) {
        int comparenrPagPublicate = ((Autor)    CompareAutor).getNrPagPublicate(); 
    //ascending order
    return this.nrPagPublicate - comparenrPagPublicate;
    //descending order
    //return compareQuantity - this.quantity;        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    public void setNrPagPublicate(int nrPagPublicate) {
        this.nrPagPublicate = nrPagPublicate;
    }
    //constructor de copiere
    public Autor(Autor c){
        nume = c.nume;
        nrPagPublicate = c.nrPagPublicate;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Autor ion = new Autor("ion",23);
        Autor ion2 = new Autor("ion2",2);
        compareTo();
    } 
}
```

amd in my interface i have

```
public interface Comparable<Autor> {
    public int compareTo(Autor CompareAutor);
}
```

Comment: it should be this :`Autor implements Comparable<Autor>`

Comment: @Ramanlfc i have that line in the beginning of the file file... my problem is that i do not know how to call the method compareTo(); in my void main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options - either implement Comparable intergace or write standalone Comparator interface.

Both options are well described at http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/ .

You can then put the items into array and sort using Arrays class:

```
Author[] authors = new Author[]{ ion, ion2, ion3, ... };
Arrays.sort(authors);
// now you would see the ion2 as first element in the array, ion as second element etc.
```

Comment: I have done this code using that exact tutorial, but it does not show how to call your method compareTO(); and that`s where I got stuck :(

Comment: It's not usually called directly but by java sort utilities, for example [Arrays.sort(Object[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])). It compares the objects in the array and sorts them according to result from compareTo.